# No match for operator '='

Tags: c++

Hi I'm a beginner C++ developer..I have a problem with a code that I post so it's easier to understand the problem.

```
Obj.h

    class Obj : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
   typedef void (*factionState)();
   struct Tran {
    factionState Action;
    unsigned int nextState;
    };

   void processAction(myState) 
   {
     Tran const*t = myarrayAction + myState
     *(t->action)();
     myState=t->nextState;
   }

 private:
     Tran const *myarrayAction; 
      unsigned int numStates;

protected:
    myObj;
    myState;    

 public:
    Obj (Tran *arrayAction,  const int nStates, const int i) {arrayAction=myarrayAction, numStates = nStates;};

   void doNothing(){printf ("Do NOthing called\n")};

Obj_1.h

    #include "Obj.h"

const int Obj_1=1
class Obj_1 : public Obj
{
   private:
   typedef enum {
    OffState,
    InitState,
    RunState,
  }state ;

  static Obj::Tran  myarrayAction[3];

  public:

    Obj_1() : Obj(myarrayAction, 3, Obj_1) {myState=OffState, myObj=Obj_1,init();};

  private:
    void init();
    void GoToInitState();
    void GoToRunState();
};

Obj_1.cpp

    void  Obj_1::init()
{
    myarrayAction[3] = {
    {&Obj::doNothing, OffState},
    {&Obj_1::GoToInitState, InitState},
    {&Obj_1::GoToRunState, RunState},
    };
}
void  Obj_1::GoToInitState()
{
// code;
}
void  Obj_1::GoToRunState()
{
// code;
}
```

When I build the code I have this error:

no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Obj::Tran' and ''). So I tried to remove '=' and write Obj1::init like this

```
myarrayAction[3] {
    {&Obj::doNothing, OffState},
    {&Obj_1::GoToInitState, InitState},
    {&Obj_1::GoToRunState, RunState},
};
```

But I have a sintax error..Any ideas??
Thanks

Comment: I'm not too fond of the syntax but it looks like you're trying to set three values into one array element.. try to take the [3] out instead of the =

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things.  First, when `Obj_1::init()` executes, `myarrayAction` has already been initialized by the constructor.  The `{ }` syntax, which works for some array initializations, is not going to work here.  You need an object (not a list of initializers) on the right-hand side of `=`.

Second, it looks like you want `Obj_1::init()` to set the contents of all three of the `Obj::Tran` objects within `myarrayAction`.  But when you start a statement like this, `myarrayAction[3] =`, it is going to try to set the array member `myarrayAction[3]`, that is, the fourth member of the array `myarrayAction` (whose first three members are `myarrayAction[0]`, `myarrayAction[1]`, `myarrayAction[2]`).  But this array has only three members.

You are better off to write something like this:

```
myarrayAction[0] = ... ;
myarrayAction[1] = ... ;
myarrayAction[2] = ... ;
```

In the `...` parts you call the constructors of the three objects you want to store at those three locations, passing the values you want to the parameters of each of these constructors.

Another thing you could do is, instead of using `Obj::Tran*` to represent an array of `Obj::Tran`, actually use a class to implement this array.  If you know STL you could write `std::vector<Obj::Tran>`, for example.  Or you could write your own class, depending on what you want.  If you write a class, you can also write a constructor that takes the list of values you want as parameters, though you will not be able to organize them into sublists with nested `{ }` as you could with an array initializer list.

Comment: Sorry only to know if I understand your answer.. When you say You need an object (not a list of initializers) on the right-hand side of =.. You intend that I have to define another class?

Comment: If you want to write `myarrayAction =`, then yes, I think you need another class. If you just want to try the first suggestion, `myarrayAction[0] = `, etc., then you have already defined the class you need to put on the right of the `=`. It is `Obj::Tran`.

Comment: Ah, just realized `Obj::Tran` is declared `struct`, not `class`. But as far as the C++ compiler is concerned, a `struct` is a kind of class with just a few differences. You can still implement a constructor for it. (Or there may be a compiler-generated constructor for what you want; I always implement the constructors I want as a matter of style, so I do not remember exactly what the compiler would provide otherwise.)